# Recoding categorical labels in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with recoding some categorical labels.Here is my minimal example that works.

```
import pandas as pd
testDict = {'Col1' : pd.Categorical(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]),
          'Col2' : pd.Categorical(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])}

testDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(testDict)
testDF
testDF['Col1'].value_counts()
def letter_recode(Col1):
    if(Col1=="a")|(Col1=="b"):
        return "ab"
    elif (Col1=="c")|(Col1=="d"):
        return "cd"
    else:
        return Col1

testDF['Col3'] = testDF['Col1'].apply(letter_recode)

testDF['Col3'].value_counts()
testDF
```

I want to change this df:

```
   Col1 Col2
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   3
3   d   4
4   e   5
```

to this:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0   a   1   ab
1   b   2   ab
2   c   3   cd
3   d   4   cd
4   e   5   e
```

The above works but when I tried this code on my real data frame, no change is happening. Also, when I tried creating a smal slice of my data frame and running the code I got the error below and didn't understand the documentation related to it.

```
df5 = df.loc[0:4,:]
df5
    age workclass   fnlwgt  education   education-num   marital-status  occupation  relationship    race    sex capital-gain    capital-loss    hours-per-week  native-country  salary  workclassR
0   50  Self-emp-not-inc    83311   Bachelors   13  Married-civ-spouse  Exec-managerial Husband White   Male    0   0   13  United-States   <=50K   Self-emp-not-inc
1   38  Private 215646  HS-grad 9   Divorced    Handlers-cleaners   Not-in-family   White   Male    0   0   40  United-States   <=50K   Private
2   53  Private 234721  11th    7   Married-civ-spouse  Handlers-cleaners   Husband Black   Male    0   0   40  United-States   <=50K   Private
3   28  Private 338409  Bachelors   13  Married-civ-spouse  Prof-specialty  Wife    Black   Female  0   0   40  Cuba    <=50K   Private
4   37  Private 284582  Masters 14  Married-civ-spouse  Exec-managerial Wife    White   Female  0   0   40  United-States   <=50K   Private

def rename_workclass(wc):
    if(wc=="Never-worked")|(wc=="Without-pay"):
        return "Unemployed"
    elif (wc=="State-gov")|(wc=="Local-gov"):
        return "Gov"
    elif (wc=="Self-emp-inc")|(wc=="Self-emp-not-inc"):
        return "Self-emp"
    else:
        return wc


df5['workclassR'] = df5['workclass'].apply(rename_workclass)
```

> C:\Users\karol\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:12:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   if sys.path[0] == '':

Many thanks for help, my problem were whitespaces in front of the values. I was trying to compare them to a string without a whitespace. Also, the error above can be removed by declaring that the sliced dataset is not a copy:

```
df5 = df.iloc[0:4, :]  # to access the column at the nth position
df5.is_copy = False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.Series.map` with a dictionary, then `fillna` with the original series:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : pd.Categorical(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]),
                   'Col2' : pd.Categorical(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])})

mapper = {'a': 'ab', 'b': 'ab', 'c': 'cd', 'd': 'cd'}

df['Col3'] = df['Col1'].map(mapper).fillna(df['Col1'])

print(df['Col3'].value_counts())

cd    2
ab    2
e     1
Name: Col3, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use `pd.Series.map()`. A toy example here:

```
s = s.map({"Private": "Private-changed", 
       "Public": "Public_changed",
       "?": "What is this"})
s
```

This gives you:

```
0    Private-changed
1     Public_changed
2       What is this
```